# How to Run Http Samplers in sequence order (step by step as per the ThreadGroup Order)

Tags: json, performance, testing, jmeter, performance-testing

Behavior of my application:

```
HTTP Request Login
..JSON Path Extractor - Im extracting the session id
Debug Sample - Checking the session id
HTTP Request -- Im passing the session id to these requests
HTTP Request -- Im passing the session id to these requests
HTTP Request -- Im passing the session id to these requests
```

If I run the above script for one time Im getting the expected results above requests are passing step by step process.

If I run the above script with - Number of Threads as 5 .Then Login is hitting for 3 times other urls hitting for 2 times.

I need to run the above script one order for number of times.

Comment: With 5 threads you should be hitting all requests by all threads. Can you provide more info as to how the thread group is setup - preferably with screenshots.

Comment: @OphirPrusak I dont have reputation to add pics Shall I send u in mail  ? Could you share ur mail id

Comment: add a link to the pics using http://imgur.com/ or something like that

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/curw1 - Please check the images in this link.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/curw1 - Please check the images in this link. Issue is im getting invalid sessions.If I run more than 2 threads.If I run for single time - I'm getting correct session with expected response

Comment: In third image you can see the expected response.In fourth image shows how we are passing the sessions(highlighted)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing any regular expression extractor which you would need to pass in the session ID from one request to another. Also, if your back end uses cookies make sure to add the http cookie manager.

Here are some good JMeter getting started videos which also cover what you're trying to do:
http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-tutorial-video-series